# Why using Grsync to synchronize pendrives in opensuse leap 15.5 , when I insert them in a windows10 OS they are seen as corrupted even if they work?

Tags: backup, opensuse, synchronization

When I use grsync in opensuse leap 15.5 to synchronize pendrives, it works perfectly , only when I insert one of those pendrives in a windows10 OS they are seen as corrupted and a correction is suggested.
If I skip the correction they work without problems, then , when i try to unmount them,  windows states that there are open files and i should close them before unmount if i don't want them corrupted. No files are open and no way to stop windows to declare it.
this doesn't happen to other pendrives .

Comment: Sounds Like you pulled them from your Linux machine before they were finished being unmounted, and the files are incomplete

Comment: I know it sounds like it , but I take care not to do it and it happens only to the synchronized ones

Comment: what exactly do you do to make sure not to do it? Also, what's the file system (and if NTFS, what's the file system driver you're using9?

Comment: That! What filesystem? And how does it get mounted/unmounted in Linux?

Comment: @Harlequin it's great you've solved the problem. Please write it as an answer (that tomorrow you can accept) rather than updating the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts, the problem seems to be due to the fact that the antivirus has automatic control of the pendrive by default and starts scanning it as soon as one is inserted. I don't know why the above mentioned errors are generated. I only know that once this automation was disabled the problem magically disappeared.